# Convert five-year data to annual data and calculate new records in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I was hoping someone could help me with this problem. I’m working with time series data that has records every five years. The data frame `df` is an example, with the time step in `df$Time` and record values in  `df$A`.

```
df
Time    A
5   4.8
10  19.6
15  27.5
20  39.7
```

What I need to do is convert `df` to an annual time series and populate all the new records with new values based on a calculation. I have successfully converted `df` to annual data `df2` using the following:

```
df2  <- data.frame("Time" = c(5:20), "A" = c(5:20))
df2$A[] <- sapply(df2$A, function(x) df$A[match(x, df$Time)])
df2[is.na(df2)] <- 0
df2
Time    A
5   4.8
6   0
7   0
8   0
9   0
10  19.6
11  0
12  0
13  0
14  0
15  27.5
16  0
17  0
18  0
19  0
20  39.7
```

What I can’t figure out is how to calculate new values for `df2$A`. The calculation depends on the relative positions of other row/record values – for example, for`df2$A[2]` the calculation would be `df2$A[2] <- df2$A[1] + (df2$A[6] - df2$A[1])/5`. It also changes throughout the data frame, for example `df2$A[7] <- df2$A[6] + (df2$A[11] – df2$A[6]) / 5`.

`for` loops have yielded only frustration, and I'm trying to do this without doing a line of code for every new record (the actual data has hundreds of records). I'm trying to get to `df3` in an efficient way - thank you!

```
df3
Time    A
5   4.8
6   7.76
7   10.72
8   13.68
9   16.64
10  19.6
11  21.18
12  22.76
13  24.34
14  25.92
15  27.5
16  29.94
17  32.38
18  34.82
19  37.26
20  39.7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is called linear interpolation. In R you can use the `approx` function like this:

```
df <- data.frame("Time" = c(5, 10, 15, 20), "A" = c(4.8, 19.6, 27.5, 39.7)) 
df2 <-  as.data.frame(approx(x = df$Time, y = df$A, xout = 5:20))
names(df2) <-  names(df)
```

Result:

```
> df2
   Time     A
1     5  4.80
2     6  7.76
3     7 10.72
4     8 13.68
5     9 16.64
6    10 19.60
7    11 21.18
8    12 22.76
9    13 24.34
10   14 25.92
11   15 27.50
12   16 29.94
13   17 32.38
14   18 34.82
15   19 37.26
16   20 39.70
```

Comment: Thank you - this worked very well. Before I saw this, I also used imputeTS library and their linear imputation function and it worked too. But approx is more straight forward

Comment: @James_S You are welcome. BTW, you should also consider the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52005833/8416610) using `zoo`. Depending on the further tasks, having an object that is meant for time series might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Create a zoo class time series object and merge it with a zero width annual
zoo object which will have the effect of filling in the missing years with `NA`.  Then apply `na.approx` to fill in the `NA` values using linear 
interpolation giving za.

(It can be optionally converted back to a data.frame using `fortify.zoo`; however, given that it is a time series it will be easier to deal with in the future if represented it as a time series and not converted it back to a data.frame.)

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(DF, FUN = identity)
g <- zoo(, start(z):end(z))  # grid
za <- na.approx(merge(z, g))

# fortify.zoo(za)
```

### Note

We used thia as the input:

```
Lines <- "Time    A
5   4.8
10  19.6
15  27.5
20  39.7"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```